# phpMyAdmin Class 'PMA_Message' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Error.class.php

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just got this error (no errors in phpMyAdmin for the last 2 years):

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PMA_Message' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Error.class.php on line 24

I tried searching the net and links like

- https://web.archive.org/web/20141102061301/http://gnuwhatimsaying.com/phpmyadmin-error-class-pma_message-not-found/ (changing the ownership of /var/lib/php/session/ folder to apache:apache - it's already set like that)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160316021748/http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2012/05/20/phpmyadmin-pma-message-class-not-found/ (quote: "I got a weird idea to see if the space is available for PHP to create sessions – gotcha, that is where my problem was. I cleaned up some unnecessary items and all went well." - to be honest I don't know what the author meant by this)

but none solved my issues, and strangely enough - these are only two links which pop up in the first 50 links of google search for this error. So, please shed some light on this.

Btw, the site which is hosted on this server works fine, DB works fine (mysql, login via SSH).

Comment: I am also having this problem on cent os. I looked at the yum log and found this `Sep 25 04:00:18 Updated: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.2-2.el6.noarch`. I am guessing something went wrong with a release and downgrading the package should fix it.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned - I'm on CentOS. Did the downgrade help you?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet...I am going to let my host do the downgrade for me (I am not great at this stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by restarting apache.

Comment: Thanks, in my case the reload was enough (service httpd reload)

Answer (score 0):

I received that error message after the **`yum update`** last night.

**Fixed** the issue **by clearing the APC opcode cache.**

Comment: I tried it by doing apc_clear_cache(), but that didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just finished fixing after 2 hours of googling...

The problem appeared because of deleting the tmp session folder (not default /var/lib/php/session in my case it was /tmp/ext_www/my.subdomain.for.phpmyadmin/)

This error message

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'PMA_Message' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Error.class.php on line 24
```

don't show actual problem. Use your logs or config to find out valid session folder.

In my case I found this by installing adminer at the phpmyadmin folder, it showed me the proper error message about "writeability" of session folder.

Sorry for my bad english, hope this could help someone

Answer (score 0):

less /etc/php.ini

session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"

ll /var/lib/php/session

drwxrwx--- 2 root apache 397312 Feb  9 10:41 session

chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path