# Phpmyadmin stopped working in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I got strange error in my phpmyadmin,interface loaded properly but i can't select the databases,tabels and all other tabs.
when i click on it nothing happend

Also there are some error messages are in console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught ReferenceError: PMA_messages is not defined
    at PMA_ajaxShowMessage
```

phpmyadmin version:4.7.1
server:nginx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin Class 'PMA\_Message' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Error.class.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036533/phpmyadmin-class-pma-message-not-found-in-usr-share-phpmyadmin-libraries-erro)

Comment: Restart apache may solve this issue

Comment: i am using nginx not apache

Comment: then try to restart php-fpm and nginx

Answer (score 2):

Its the problem with session folder permission

added 777 permission to `var/lib/php/sessions` folder now everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

The 500 code would normally indicate an error on the server, try to restart Apache `sudo service apache2 restart`, post also the content of the apache phpmyadmin.conf file of that server, it should be in /etc/apache2/conf/

Answer (score 0):

it might be various issues, but in my case phpmyadmin version is not compatible with php version. when i downloaded phpmyadmin for php7.4.
everything works fine.
i hope that might be useful for you all